Cos results in Fortran and MATLAB are different
When I calculate cos(pi/2), MATLAB and Fortran give two different results.
In MATLAB, I just input:

ans =

6.1232e-17

In Fortran:
program cal_cos

implicit none

real*8, parameter :: pi = 3.141592653589
real*8 :: c

c = cos (pi/2)

print *, "cos(pi/2) = ", c
end program cal_cos

I get a result:  cos(pi/2) =   -4.3711390001862412E-008, it's so different with MATLAB result. Fortran result does not change if I assign more digit to pi number.
Could you explain why two results are different and how to fix this?
Thanks for reading my question.

By default, a number like 3.141592653589 is default real kind.  On most systems today, this is a single precision entity with a 24-bit significand.  The function cos is a generic intrinsic procedure, so you are calling a single precision function.  To fix your issue, you need to tell the compiler that the real literal constant is double precision.  You can do this via a suffix of D0, ie., 3.141592653589D0

In addition, you are not even specifying enough digits of pi to give you the closest value to pi in a double precision variable. You should be using 3.141592653589793D0
